# iOS/Xcode - Toggle button changing position

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, tableview

I want a button that toggles the position of an element on click.

My current code:

```
-(IBAction)menuTouched{

// Push menu
UITableView * sideMenu = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661)];
sideMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:sideMenu];

// Animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^{
    sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(960, 88, 63, 661);
}];
}
```

When clicking the button it animates the tableview in just like I want to. But now I want to animate the tableview out by pressing the exact same button. So in short I want the button to toggle in and out a tableview by changing the X position. What is the best/easiest approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tolylon : Check my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `.h file` add

```
UITableView * sideMenu;
 BOOL checkInOut;
```

inside .m file add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     checkInOut=False;
    // Push menu
    sideMenu = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661)];
    sideMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:sideMenu];
}


-(IBAction)menuTouched
{
 checkInOut=!checkInOut
 if(checkInOut)
  {
   // Animate
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^{
    sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(960, 88, 63, 661);
   }];
 }
 else
  {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^{
    sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661);
   }];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im not sure what you want me to put in viewWillAppear exactly. Also im not yet familiar with the concept of using viewWillAppear.

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bool to store the state where you are, but you can just use the button.selected state for that.. Something like that:

```
- (IBAction)menuTouched:(id)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        // toggle on stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // toggle off stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
 [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
 myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,420,320,120);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform the same animation with different frame as you set previously

```
sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661);
```

with the check to see have you togged the table in or out to perform respective action.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive as UIButton reference instead of id

```
- (IBAction)menuTouched:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected;

        if (sender.selected)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^
    {
       UITableView * sideMenu = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661)];
         sideMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:sideMenu];
        sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(960, 88, 63, 661);
       }];
        }
        else
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^{
        [sideMenu removeForSuperView];
       }];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.set a flag bit to represent UITableView's current state.The statement need 3 variables.

```
BOOL isShow;
UITableView *sideMenu;
CGFloat posX;
```

2.initial setting in `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    isShow=NO;
    //to do something...
    sideMenu = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1060, 88, 63, 661)];
    sideMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:sideMenu];
}
```

3.What UITableView shows is just the change of X-coordinate of frame.so you can calculate posX depend on toggles 'state.and notice don't create UITableView at each time clicking.put the UITableView creat  code on viewDidLoad function.

```
-(IBAction)menuTouched{
   posX=isShow ? 1060 : 960       
   // Animate
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 animations:^{
       sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(posX, 88, 63, 661);
   }];
   isShow=!isShow;  //boggle button
}
```